# A Javascript to set a new homepage in Firefox, IE, Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm wondering if there is still a working Javascript or a PHP code to set/change the startpage of a visitor for Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer ?

Just by clicking on a button ?

I found many codes but there are not working anymore..

Thank's !

Comment: I doubt you are going to find anything in this day in age. It was popular pre 1999.

Comment: I sure hope not